# Namespace conflict with phpUnit

Tags: php, ubuntu, namespaces, phpunit

> file to be tested:
> /a/b/c/api/localclass/s/taxinformationrepository.class.phptest:
>
> /a/b/c/api/tests/_helpers/TestTaxInformationRepository_class.php
>
> phpUnit directory location:
>
> /a/b/c/api/phpUnit/
>
> composer.json:
>
> {
>
> ```
> "require": {  
>
>     "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6"  
>
> },
> "autoload": { 
>     "psr-4": {"App\\\\": "/a/b/c/api/localclass/s/"} 
> }, 
> "autoload-dev": {
>     "psr-4": {"App\\\\Tests\\\\": "/a/b/c/api/tests/\_helpers/"} 
> }
> ```
>
> }

TestTaxInformationRepository_class.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Tests;

use App\S_TaxInformationRepository;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class TestTaxInformationRepository_class extends TestCase{

    public function GetConceptInputsAnnual_lePasoArrayDevuelveString(): void
    {
        $getConceptInputsAnnualArray=['year' => 2022, 'account' => '4600015', 'accountMatrixPosition' => "when '46000015' then (1)"];
        $taxinformationrepository_class=new S_TaxInformationRepository();
        $resultado=$taxinformationrepository_class->getConceptInputsAnnual($getConceptInputsAnnualArray);
        $this->assertEquals('hola',$resultado);
    }
}
```

taxinformationrepository.class.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

public static function getConceptInputsAnnual($conditionsArray)
    {
        $resultData = [];
        $year                   = $conditionsArray["year"];
        $account                = $conditionsArray["account"];
        $accountMatrixPosition  = $conditionsArray['accountMatrixPosition'];

        $sql = "SELECT tblCO.COCODIGO AS 'col01',
                    tblGM.GMSPCODE AS 'col02',
                    tblCY.CYCCY AS 'col03',
                    '' AS 'col04',
                    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(tblGM.GMOPEDATE,7,2),'/', SUBSTRING(tblGM.GMOPEDATE,5,2), '/',SUBSTRING(tblGM.GMOPEDATE,1,4))  AS 'col05',
                    tblGM.GMVOLUME AS 'col06',
                    tblGM.GMPRICE AS 'col07',
                    (tblGM.GMCORRETAJE + tblGM.GMLIQUIDADORCOM + tblGM.GMCONTRATACIONCOM + tblGM.GMGESTIONCOM + tblGM.GMSCLCOM 
                    + tblGM.GMOTHERSCOM + tblGM.GMCLIENTCOM + tblGM.GMTOBINTAX) AS 'col08', 
                    (tblGM.GMEXCHANGE * tblGM.GMGROSSAMOUNT) AS 'col09',
                    tblGM.GMGROSSAMOUNT AS 'col10',
                    CASE GMSPCODE 
                        {$accountMatrixPosition}
                    END AS 'col11',
                    tblGM.GMISIN AS 'colTo_isin',
                    tblGM.GMCODOPERATION AS 'colTo_opeCode',
                    tblGM.GMTIPOMOV AS 'colTo_isAnulated',
                    tblGM.GMEXCHANGE AS 'colTo_exchangeRate',
                    tblGM.GMCCY AS 'colTo_DivisaCode'
                FROM BAGCMOVEMENT AS tblGM
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                        COSIGNOTITULOS,
                        COCODIGO,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COCODIGO ORDER BY COINDEX) AS code_rn
                    FROM BACONCEPTOSTMP) tblCO ON 
                    tblGM.GMTYPE = tblCO.COCODIGO AND tblCO.code_rn = 1
                    LEFT JOIN BACCY AS tblCY ON
                    tblGM.GMCCY = tblCY.CYCODE
                WHERE tblGM.GMSPCODE IN ({$account}) AND
                    tblCO.COSIGNOTITULOS = '+'
                          AND tblCO.COCODIGO IS NOT NULL
                    AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, tblGM.GMOPEDATE)) = {$year}
                    ORDER BY tblGM.GMOPEDATE, 'colTo_isin' ASC;";

        $resultData = SQL::fetchAll($sql, 'BACKOFFICE', Config::get('BKDB', 'SQL'));
        return $resultData;
    }
```

Then I run the test by command line:

```
-$./vendor/bin/phpunit /home/administrador/Documentos/api-es-front-01/tests/_helpers/TestTaxInformationRepository_class.php
```

And then I get the following:

> PHPUnit 9.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
> W                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
> Time: 00:00.002, Memory: 4.00 MB
> There was 1 warning:
>
> 1. Warning No tests found in class "App\Tests\TestTaxInformationRepository_class".
>    WARNINGS!
>    Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.

Why is not finding the test? I expected something like:

> PHPUnit 9.6.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
> F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
> Time: 00:00.113, Memory: 4.00 MB
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1. App\Tests\TestTaxInformationRepository_class::getConceptInputsAnnual_lePasoArrayDevuelveString
>    Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
>    --- Expected
>    +++ Actual
>    @@ @@
>    -'hola'
>    +'(large amount of data)'
>
> /a/b/c/api/tests/_helpers/TestTaxInformationRepository_class.php:14
> FAILURES!
> Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Comment: Don't methods have to start with `test` in a phpUnit testfile? Also, what is the exact "_Namespace conflict_" error you get?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue by adding

> /** @test */

before the function

Thanks!